# bindToController without creating new scope

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to come up with a good strategy for managing directives and components in Angular (1.4) when using `bindToController`. I have two factory functions to build directives and components respectively, where I set default values. [I have set up an example here](http://codepen.io/niclassahlin/pen/27e8d360e1a25078c7ea4311d587d0c1?editors=101).

In short, there is a `main` component with an isolated scope, and it is using a `textColor` directive that sets the text color of an element. The issue with this setup is that since the `textColor` directive does not create a new scope, it will overwrite the `vm` property on the scope and replace the reference to the `main` controller.

Basically, what I trying to accomplish is to be able to access attribute values in the directives' controllers, without having to parse them in the `link` function. I also want the classes to be as clean as possible, so the upgrade to Angular 2 will be as smooth as it can be.

A solution I have now is to append a random GUID to the controller alias for directives (since I don't use them in any templates anyway), but it feels like a dirty way of solving this.

Is there a "clean" solution for this?